# Using "the" for "the web designers"

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> The underlying assumption is that **the** web designers utilize visual cues such as horizontal or vertical lines, colored panels, boxes, special fonts or background images, to discriminate different regions of a web page.

Does "web designers" here needs "the". I don't know why, but I feel with "the", I can read it easier!!? Moreover, I just thought by using "the" I can distinguish a type of people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English differs from some other languages in its usage of "**the**" (the definite article).

English does *not* use "**the**" before general categories. "**The**" is only used with nouns that can explicitly enumerated.

**Omit definite article:**

General category, you don't have specific individuals in mind:

> Web designers are smart people

Still a general category; it only has an extra specifier. You still don't have specific individuals in mind:

> Web designers from Google are highly motivated

**Include definite article:**

Now you have specific individuals in mind; you can list them out by name:

> The web designers went out to lunch (that is, Alice, Bob, and Carol)

**Contrast with Spanish**

Spanish for example, uses the definite article with categories, unlike English.

If you enter "Programmers are smart" into Google translate from English to Spanish, you'll get:

> Los programadores son inteligentes

Where "los" is the definite article.

**More Info on categories**

There are cases when you'd use the definite article with categories, but only indirectly. For example, in this case, "**the**" is modifying "subject" and not the category.

> The subject of web designers intrigues me

---

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Use_of_articles

Answer (score 3):

If you are 'specific' about those web designers (say from ABC Company), then yes, you *do* require it.

If you are referring to web designers in general, you can drop it. Said that, without the definite article, it'll address to all web designers.

Comment: I just thought by using "the" I can distinguish a type of people!

Comment: That's true but not in this case. Imagine a room filled with programmers, designers and writers. You may go and announce, "The programmers will move to the right side". It then 'distinguishes'! :)

Comment: @Ahmad that is correct, but "distinguish" means you are talking about the *difference* between *two* (or more than two) groups of people. The sentence in your question only mentions *one* group, "web designers". If the next sentence said that "programmers" do something different from web designers, then "the web designers" and "the programmers" would be correct, because the *two sentences taken together* are distinguishing between two groups of people.